# Why (balance == wei) return false, when I use ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, bsc, ethereumj

I'm begin learn ethers.js. I wrote like this

```
    const balance = await provider.getBalance("0x862...99");
    const ether = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
    const wei = ethers.utils.parseEther(ether);
    console.log(wei == balance)
```

I see `wei` and `balance` are BigNumber and have same value. But I don't know why `(wei == balance)` returns false.
Please help me. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

After research, I see `wei` and `balace` are BigNumber, greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (2^53-1).
So `wei == balance` give wrong result.
I managed to use function `formatUnits` of ethers.js when compare those BigNumbers and I have correct result.